# NTC resistance/temperature deviation from nominal value

Tags: sensor, thermistor

In the datasheet of [this NTC](https://www.vishay.com/docs/29049/ntcle100.pdf) I found this section:

[image]

I understand the steps, but it is not clear to me in the end where do I observe this temperature variation?

Here are my calculations:

Assuming from the datasheet the worst cases where:
X = 5% (R_25 tolerance)
Y = 5% (beta_25 tolerance)
(tell me if they are correct .. I may have read them wrong in the datasheet!)

Following exactly the steps described in the picture, I found deltaT = 1.86°C.
But **where do I observe this temperature variation? AT 25°C? AT 0°C? AT 50°C?**